# Visual Studio Intellisense and Concepts

Tags: c++, visual-studio, templates, c++20, c++-concepts

The following code compiles fine on Clang, GCC and on Visual Studio.

The only thing that fails is Visual Studio Intellisense while hovering over the `v` variable.

Is my code well defined?

Is this just a setback from Visual Studio Intellisense not being able to catch on with C++ newest features?

If I change the concept implementation to bare templates, Intellisense will be happy and work correctly. I want that same behaviour but constrained.

```
#include <concepts>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

// Just a constexpr dummy!
template <typename T>
struct Hash {
    [[nodiscard]] static constexpr std::size_t
    get(T) noexcept {
        return 13;
    }
};

template <typename T>
concept Hashable = requires(T a) {
    { Hash<T>::get(a) } -> std::same_as<std::size_t>;
};

[[nodiscard]] constexpr auto
hash_combine(std::size_t const a, std::size_t const b) noexcept {
    return a ^ (b + 0x9E3779B9 + (a << 6) + (a >> 2));
}

//template <typename A>
template <Hashable A>
[[nodiscard]] constexpr auto
hash(A const & a) noexcept {
    return Hash<A>::get(a);
}

//template <typename A, typename B>
template <Hashable A, Hashable B>
[[nodiscard]] constexpr auto
hash(A const & a, B const & b) noexcept {
    return hash_combine(hash(a), hash(b));
}

//template <typename A, typename B, typename... C>
template <Hashable A, Hashable B, Hashable... C>
[[nodiscard]] constexpr auto
hash(A const & a, B const & b, C const &... c) noexcept {
    auto value = hash(a, b);
    return ((value = hash(value, c)), ...);
}

int
main() {
    constexpr auto v = hash(1, 2, 3);
    std::cout << v << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: As far as I know "requires" keyword in a function template is not supported yet by intellisense. https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1269227/intellisense-error-when-using-requires-keyword-in.html

Comment: At present, VS Intellisense only implements initial syntax support for `concepts`. As `concepts` are still a preview feature, supported only under `/std:c++latest`, the implementation in IntelliSense is incomplete, and unable to handle the standard `<concepts>` header. A future release will have full concepts support in IntelliSense. Also, you could vote in this [link](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/1140473/-cpp-lib-concepts-isnt-defined-in-vs-2019-1630-rel.html).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, here is how I solved it:

Inside VS-Code press

**ctrl+shift+P**

then type in

**C/C++: Select IntelliSense Configuration..**

and choose

**g++10**

I hope this helps <3