# IntelliSense suggestions for C++ Concepts in Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, intellisense, c++20, c++-concepts

I'm very new to `templates` and `concepts` and started using them in Visual Studio 2022 (17.4.2).

Here is a program that compiles, but I find that the IntelliSense it not working as I had hoped:

```cpp
struct Entity {
  int i;

  Entity(const int i_) : i(i_) {}
  virtual ~Entity() {}
};

struct A : public Entity {
  bool a;
  A(const int i_, const bool a_) : Entity(i_), a(a_) {}
};

template <class T>
concept hasI = requires(T a) { a.i; };
template <class T>
concept ofEntity = std::derived_from<T, Entity>;

// template <ofEntity T>  // doesn't make IntelliSense work either
template <hasI T>
void tfunc(const std::map<int, std::shared_ptr<T>>& m) {
  for (auto& it : m) {
// ------------------------ V -------------- No IntelliSense?
    std::cout << it.second->i << std::endl;
  }
}

static void run() {
  std::map<int, std::shared_ptr<Entity>> aMap;
  std::shared_ptr<A> myA = std::make_shared<A>(1, true);
  aMap.insert({myA->i, myA});

  tfunc(aMap);
}
```

As you can see in the marked line, I access the member, but while typing it, I do not get any suggestions. I understand that this is not working for general `templates`, but I was hoping that this would work in conjunction with `concepts`.

Having no IntelliSense in all functions with `templates` sounds very cumbersome, as errors will only show up when you compile and missing suggestions means slower coding.

From the replies [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65204326/visual-studio-intellisense-and-concepts) I expected this to be implemented by now. Is there anything I'm missing or not doing incorrectly?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: There is a difference between intellisense "compiles" the code without errors and intellisense understands that `hasI` might be auto-completed by `i` (especially as concept might be more complicated).

Comment: Why does IntelliSense "compile" the code? Either way, is there a way to get auto-completion to work?

Comment: To detect error/ propose suggestion and so on. But I don't think that auto-completion feature supports/understand concept that way.

Comment: do you mean when you typing "ofEntity" meanwhile you don't get intenllisence pop out? On my side it seems work.

Comment: @BowmanZhu-MSFT No, when typing `it->second->` it should suggest `i` as one of the / topmost options.